# Getting Spring Security Context with null authentication

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, akka

I am developing an OData Service (Java) with SDL OData Framework (https://github.com/sdl/odata) and Spring Boot.

I am facing some problems when adding security to the app through Spring Security.

In some classes that implements interfaces provided by the SDL Framework I am getting errors when a method is annotated with "@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")".

The console output is:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:378) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:222) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.getStrategy(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.sdl.odata.processor.datasource.factory.DataSourceFactoryImpl.getStrategy(DataSourceFactoryImpl.java:75) ~[odata_processor-2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sdl.odata.processor.ODataQueryProcessorImpl.query(ODataQueryProcessorImpl.java:85) ~[odata_processor-2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataQueryProcessorActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataQueryProcessorActor.scala:38) ~[odata_service-2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataQueryProcessorActor.aroundReceive(ODataQueryProcessorActor.scala:29) ~[odata_service-2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_74]
```

Part of the code of the SDL Framework is written in Scala and use the Akka toolkit.

I suppose that the exception **AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException** is related to the fact that the implemented classes required by the SDL Framework run in a different thread (thread-local) than one who created the Security Context.

So, the questions are: is this the case? If it is, how can I get the security context within these classes?

The source code is available at:https://github.com/diegocairone/sdlpoc-jpa-querydsl/tree/master/sdlpocjpa

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall it Spring uses ThreadLocal to pass context between components, in Akka there is no guarantee the same thread will execute each receive block involved in handling a message flow.

You could probably manually extract the security context while still in a thread that Spring manages, pass it along inside the messages between your actors and reinstate it in `ThreadLocal` before processing the message (don't forget to remove it afterwards, or else it will leak between messages).

Comment: I know nothing about Akka except that a third party library called SDL use it. As a user of that library I must write some classes implementing interfaces from the library.

Is within these classes where I need the Spring Security Context.

Spring Security provide to user 3 strategies to specify the way the SC will be managed through the request (My app is an odata service).

The only way I get this to work is using the strategy named MODE_GLOBAL but it is  definitely inappropriate for server use according to Spring docs.

I don't know if is there a solution outside the library.